# SwiftUI: UITextField like properties

Tags: swift, textfield, swiftui

Anyone knows how to customize a SwiftUI TextField properties such as spellCheckingType or autocorrectionType?
Doing this without interfacing with UIKit at all seems impossible...

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

For AutoCorrection of TextField or Text, you can try

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var name: String = "Angie"
    var body: some View {

            VStack {
                TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
                Text("Hello, \(name)!")
            }
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
    }
}
```

And i'm not sure about spellChecking in SwiftUI, but you can look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield for modifying it.

I hope it will help you in customization of TextField!

Thanks!!